# How to do Pai kui and the Cheet jeung techniques?

Tags: punching

My friend and I are practicing southern style mantis kung fu, but we do not have an academy that teaches this.

How do those two techniques work?

It would be great with pictures, but if not, no problem.

Comment: Cheet Jeung is "cutting palm". Pai Kui is "slicing hand". Both are techniques in the SPM style.

Comment: One other thing: Southern praying mantis is a very complex, subtle, difficult to learn and master style. It uses internal mechanics. I'm afraid that learning from pictures is not very likely without someone instructing you.

Comment: I've trained in a chow gar / 7 star mixed school for a few years, and to be truthful we never used the Cantonese names for techniques.  When I googled Pai Kui, it's the 4th form in the Chow Gar system. Not sure what exactly is meant by 'cutting palm' (I could think of several things that could be it).  Forget about learning it without a teacher.  There are also a number of 'secret' techniques that you'll never see on the internet (or at least you shouldn't)